# Algorithm to create "Spot It"/"Dobble" cards, but with two common images from any two cards

Tags: algorithms

In the ordinary "Spot It"/"Dobble" game, there is exactly one common image between any two cards. At the moment I am trying to modify the algorithms already available on the internet so that any two cards have two, three, etc. elements in common.

Unfortunately, I have failed and am now looking for ideas on how such an algorithm could look in concrete terms. Do you have any ideas for such an algorithm?

[image: https://www.games4all.ee/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/cards.jpg]

Comment: *Spot It* can more or less be modeled as a projective plane of order $7$: There are $7^2 + 7 + 1 = 57$ symbols, representing the points in the plane, and the cards correspond to the 57 lines in the plane: Each pair of lines intersects in exactly one points, i.e., each two distinct cards have precisely one symbol in common. (For whatever reason, maybe because of printing constraints, *Spot It* only includes 55 of the 57 cards/"lines".)

Comment: I don't know of a general algorithm for producing interesting solutions, but there is a trivial solution: One each card, duplicate each symbol, and then for each symbol, on each card where it appears, recolor one of the two copies of the symbol in a particular way. So, e.g., each card that had a (red) ladybug in the original deck now has one red ladybug and one green ladybug, and likewise for all of the other symbols.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, that's how I'm implementing it currently. 

If you play the game a few times, you will know at some point - as in your example - that the red ladybug always goes with the green one. It would be great, if I could find a way so that the symbols don't always appear in pairs, making the search a little more challenging.

Comment: There's another trivial method of generating sets of cards so that any two cards have exactly $n$ symbols in common: Pick $n + 2$ symbols, and for each symbol, make a card that excludes only that symbol, so that each card has $n + 1$ symbols.

Comment: I wrote [a blog post about how to construct Spot It](https://blog.plover.com/math/finite-projective-planes.html) decks that might be helpful. I don't know how to modify the method to have every pair of cards overlap in two or three symbols. I think the keyword you want to search for is "combinatorial designs".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who's interested: I used the advice posted in this comment:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65780880/algorithm-to-create-spot-it-dobble-cards-but-with-two-common-images-from-an#comment116311020_65780880

So let's assume I take two decks of cards with completely different images.

```
A1     B1
A2     B2
A3     B3
...    ...
An     Bn
```

Now, all those cards get shuffled

```
A23     B50
A4      B12
A18     B17
...     ....
```

and combined into one large card.

```
A23 + B50
A4  + B12
A18 + B17
...   ....
```

This will result in two images matching between each pair of cards (one of set A and one of set B)

Answer (score 2):

One can generate such a deck with a [**symmetric block design**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design#Symmetric_2-designs_(SBIBDs)), which consists of

- a set $\mathcal S$ (of symbols)
- a collection $\mathcal C$ of subsets of $\mathcal S$ called **blocks**---in our case, cards---such that there are as many cards as there are symbols, and each $2$-subset of symbols occurs on equally many, say, $\lambda$, cards.

This concept is a special case of the concept of *combinatorial design*.

If we denote by

- $v$ the number of symbols, equivalently the number of cards, and
- $k$ the number of cards in which any given symbol appears---which for symmetric designs is the same as the number of symbols on each card---

then $$\lambda (v - 1) = k (k - 1) ,$$

and we call a design with given parameters a $(v, k, \lambda)$-design. The **order** of a symmetric design is $k - \lambda$.

It turns out that every two distinct cards have $\lambda$ symbols in common, so $(v, k, 1)$-designs (with $k > 2$) correspond to projective planes and therefore to the *Spot-It* like games outlined in [MJD's blog post](https://blog.plover.com/math/finite-projective-planes.html) mentioned in the comments, and the question is asking about the construction of $(v, k, \lambda)$-designs with $\lambda > 1$.

There are lots of constructions for producing these:

**Example 1 (faces of $n$-simplices)** One easy construction is taking a set of $n$ symbols and making $n$ cards, each of which omits one of the symbols, so that each pair of cards intersects in $n - 2$ symbols, giving a $(n, n - 1, n - 2)$ design, which thus has order $1$. (We can think of such a design as an $n$-simplex, the cards as the codimension-$1$ faces of the simplex, and the sets of symbols common to two given cards as the codimension-$2$ face at which the corresponding faces meet.)

**Example 2 (complementary designs)** Given any $(v, k, \lambda)$-design, we can produce a $(v, v - k, \lambda + v - 2 k)$-design by replacing the set of symbols on each card with the complement of that set. The new design is called the **complement** of the old one and the two designs have the same orders.

**Example 3 (Hadamard designs)** For any [Hadamard matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer_configuration) of size $(4 m) \times (4 m)$, we can construct a $(4 m - 1, 2 m - 1, m - 1)$-design (called a **Hadamard $2$-design**), which thus has order $m$: By rearranging rows and columns of the Hadamard matrix, we can arranging for the first row and first column to have all entries $+1$. Delete that row and column, that is, consider the lower-right $(4 m - 1) \times (4 m - 1)$ minor $\Lambda$. Then, for each $(i, j)$ the card $C_j$ includes the $i$th symbol if and only if $\Lambda_{ij} = -1$.

**Example 4 (Grassmannians of hyperplanes over finite fields)** For any finite field $\Bbb F_q$ and any dimension $d \geq 2$, let the symbols and cards be the lines and hyperplanes, respectively, in $\Bbb F_q^{d + 1}$, and declare that a symbol $\ell$ is on a card $H$ if and only if $\ell \subset H$. This defines a $\left(\frac{q^{d + 1} - 1}{q - 1}, \frac{q^d - 1}{q - 1}, \frac{q^{d - 1} - 1}{q - 1}\right)$-design, which thus has order $q^{d - 1}$. The special case $d = 2$ yields projective planes.

A design with $\lambda = 2$---that is, a deck so that any two distinct cards have exactly two symbols is common---is called a **biplane**. A biplane of order $m$ corresponds to a deck with $\frac{1}{2} (m^2 + 3 m + 4)$ symbols and as many cards.

- The only biplane of order $0$ corresponds to a trivial deck of $2$ cards, each of which have the same $2$ symbols:
  $$01, \qquad 01$$
- The only biplane of order $1$ is given by taking $n = 4$ in Example 1:
  $$012, \qquad 013, \qquad 023, \qquad 123$$
- The only biplane of order $2$ is the complement (Example 2) of the **Fano plane**, the smallest of the projective planes, i.e., the projective plane $\Bbb P(\Bbb F_2^3)$ corresponding to the $2$-element field $\Bbb F_2$:
  $$0136, \qquad 0145, \qquad 0235, \qquad 0246, \qquad 1234, \qquad 1256, \qquad 3456 .$$
- The only biplane of order $3$ arises from the unique Hadamard design (Example 3) with $m = 3$. Since $11$ is prime, we can apply the [Paley construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley_construction) to produce a $12 \times 12$ Hadamard matrix and hence an $11$-card deck:
  \begin{multline}
  01247, \quad
  0136\textrm{A}, \quad
  0259\textrm{A}, \quad
  03789, \quad
  04568, \quad
  12358, \\
  1489\textrm{A}, \quad
  15679, \quad
  23469, \quad
  2678\textrm{A}, \quad
  3457\textrm{A} .
  \end{multline}
  This configuration is called the **Paley biplane**, and it corresponds to the [exceptional inclusion $PSL(2, 5) \hookrightarrow PSL(2, 11)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_linear_group#Action_on_p_points).
- There are several distinct biplanes of order $4$, including one arising from the classic [Kummer configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer_configuration), which corresponds to a deck of $16$ cards and as many symbols.
- The [Bruck-Ryser-Chowla Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruck%E2%80%93Ryser%E2%80%93Chowla_theorem) implies that there are no biplanes of order $5$ or $6$.

I haven't seen the term before, but one might as call a design with $\lambda = 3$ a **triplane**; a triplane of order $m$ corresponds to a deck with $\frac{1}{3} (m^2 + 5 m + 9)$ symbols and as many cards, so a triplane cannot have order equivalent to $2 \pmod 3$.

- There is a triplane of order $0$ analogous to the trivial biplane.
- Taking $n = 5$ in Example $1$ gives a triplane of order $1$.
- The dual of the Paley biplane is a triplane of order $3$.
- Taking $q = 2, d = 3$ in Example 4 gives a triplane of order $4$, and it corresponds to a deck of $15$ cards and as many symbols.